# Retrieving JS script from a website using Python3

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, python-requests

I would like to scrape a website for its "raw" JavaScript code. For example, if I were to scrape [this](https://www.udemy.com) website. I would get a string containing:

[image]

This is just a small portion of the existing JS in the given link, but I would like to obtain the entire JS in a string or array of strings.

I have tried different approaches to obtain this data: using `requests` and `selenium`.
Simply loading the HTML of the website doesn't seem to work, as the script tags don't seem to load.

Using `selenium`, I hoped this would work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.udemy.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "script")))

print(results)
```

Then using `results` I could get a string, but it doesn't work.

Another example for the JS Scripts chunks I'd like to get:

[image]

The red rectangle indicates JS Scripts, as you can see there is a lot of it and I would like to get it in its "raw" form (not execute it).

My question is: How would I get the "raw" JS script in a string format? and what is the most efficient way (time-wise) to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `.get_attribute('innerHTML')`.  You also do not want to use `visibility_of_all_elements_located` since you are looking for something that will not ever be visible.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.udemy.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

#wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
#results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "script")))

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
script_tag = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//script")))
innerHTML_of_script_tag = []
for script in script_tag:
    innerHTML_of_script_tag.append(script.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    print(script.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    print("################################################################")

print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(innerHTML_of_script_tag)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This code doesn't seem to get the entire JS script found in the website. Though it is able to obtain some script, some larger sections of it (as shown in the image in the question itself) are missing and are empty in `innerHTML_of_script_tag` as well as in the `print` statement. It's those parts that I am having trouble retrieving.

Comment: @Omer Hen When I go to https://www.udemy.com/ I am not seeing that large block of javascript from your screenshot. Are you interacting with the page in any way before you are seeing this block of java script code?

Comment: I added another image showing the large chunks of JS script. The given code doesn't really seem to capture all that. Apart from that, I simply load the website and go to the "inspect" option given by Chrome to view the source code. I don't perform any special operations or interact with the page.

Comment: @Omer Hen Small update, this is interesting I can see the block you are looking for when I print the `driver.page_source` to a text file but not in the attribute `innerHTML`.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find a solution to. Also, when I printed `driver.page_source` I didn't see the large chunks of JS script, but only a few smaller chunks.

Comment: @Omer Hen Try adding a `time.sleep(7)` after the `driver.get`. Then see if `driver.page_source` has it.

Comment: I added `time.sleep(7)` but still it doesn't seem to get the larger parts of the script. Do you maybe know why `innerHTML` doesn't work in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206295/discussion-between-jortega-and-omer-hen).